# Is there a way to always pass by value (Make a copy) rather than passing by reference when working with class member functions?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

For a little background, I have been studying c++ for 3 months so I'm basically a newbie and I'm trying to understand classes that contain raw pointers as data members and how to use copy-contractors and move semantics with them.

So I have this simple class that contains a simple constructor/destructor and an unimplemented copy-constructor.

All I'm doing is creating an object using said class and then calling a member function with it.

So my question is:

Can I somehow always guaranty that when I call a member function I will make a copy of the object calling it and not pass it by reference?

You can easily pass something by reference if you add the "&" operator but what about passing something by value?
I have read that pass by value is the default way the compiler does it but for some reason when I execute my code the copy constructor is not called.

```
using namespace std;

    class dog {
    public:
        string* name;
        int* age;

        dog(string NameVal = { "Null" }, int AgeVal = { 10 }) { 
            name = new string{ NameVal };
            age = new int{ AgeVal };
            cout << "constructor for " << *name << endl;
        }
        ~dog() {
            cout << "destructor for " << *name << " " << age << endl;
        }
        dog(const dog &source) {
            cout << "copy constructor for " << *name << endl;
        }
        void talk(string text) {
            cout << text << *name << endl;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        dog test;

        test.talk("Test_Text ");
        return 0;
    }
```

So I expected the copy constructor to get called for the test object but it looks like it gets passed by reference using the "this" pointer.

How could I change that and actually make a copy of the object when calling the function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just to make it clear. In Your example, you want `test.talk()` to create a new dog, call `talk()` on it and immediately destroy it? If so, why?

Comment: you can also just create a temporary `dog` and call the method on that too. `dog{}.talk("hi");`

Comment: @Frank I just want the test object to get copied when I call the test.talk() function with it rather than have it get passed by reference using the "This" pointer

Comment: @RaXeD The reason I am asking is that this strikes me as a XY problem, whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish by this is probably better served by some other mechanism the language provides.

Comment: @RaXeD That's not how C++ works.  Calling a method on an object calls the method on that object, not a copy of that object.  Nothing is "passed" per-say.  While a method call may be implemented as a function call with an extra hidden `this` parameter on most implementations, that is not logically what it is.

Comment: @Frank that's probably true but I don't want to accomplish anything I just want to get more experience working with copy constructors and move semantics and for that, I need to get the copy constructor called and then implement a move function to see how they work together.

Comment: Member functions are applied to an object they are invoked on, not to its copy. If you want to make a copy, make a copy. `auto copy = original;` Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to copy the object and then call a function on the new object then you will need to do it explicitly:

```
dog test{};
dog{test}.talk("copy talk");
```

Note that you will also need to actually implement the copy constructor for this to work, otherwise class fields will be left uninitialized:

```
dog(const dog &source)
: name{new string{*(source.name)}}
, age{new int{*(source.age)}}
{
       cout << "copy constructor for " << *name << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I wanted to do thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to always pass by value (Make a copy) rather than passing by reference when working with class member functions?

use a static operation receiving the instance by value

```
class dog {
       ...
       static void talk(dog inst, string text) {
            cout << text << *(inst.name) << endl;
        }
       ...
};

int main() {
    dog test;

    dog::talk(test, "Test_Text ");
    // or even
    test.talk(test, "Test_Text ");
}
```

Comment: That actually worked but I had to pass in the test object as a function parameter is there a way to make a copy of the object while calling the function like this: test.talk("Test_Text ");

Comment: @RaXeD you have to understand you want to not follow the behavior of the language, so for sure you have to explicitly ask for the copy whatever the way to do that ;-)